# How to Read certain texts from csv filename and insert as header inside and concatenate them as one

Tags: awk

How can i extract from this `ZZ_OUTYYYY_MM_DD_HH_TT_SS_csvfile.csv` YYYY as year, MM as month, DD as day, HH as hour, TT as minutes, SS as seconds and insert them as a header inside the same csv file. The csv file already has four columns inside and i need to add YYYY, MM, DD, HH, TT, SS after those four columns and later to concatenate all these files as one.
Please help me in solving this in a single commands flow.

I was using the following command after copying them manually

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {$4="2023_10_12_14_31_23" OFS $4; print}' ZZ_OUT2023_10_12_14_31_23_csvfile.csv > output123.csv
```

My input file(ZZ_OUT2023_10_19_12_60_60_csvfile.csv) format is:
ID, Name, OpenPrice, ClosePrice
1, ABC, 555, 560
2, DEF, 666, 670
.
.

What I want is to insert the headers of filename inside the csv as:

ID, Name, OpenPrice, ClosePrice, YYYY, MM, DD, HH, TT, SS
1, ABC, 555, 560, 2023, 10, 19, 12, 60, 60
2, DEF, 666, 670, 2023, 10, 19, 12, 60, 60
.
.
.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your sample of input and sample of expected output in your question to make it more clear, cheers.

Comment: does each csv only contain 2 lines?

Comment: No each csv file has more than 1000 entries inside.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    # print header
    NR==1 { print $0 ",YYYY,MM,DD,HH,TT,SS" }

    # initialise suffix each time new file is read
    FNR==1 {
        # skip file if name does not match format
        if (!match(FILENAME, /[0-9]{4}(_[0-9]{2}){5}/))
            nextfile

        # replace underscores with commas
        suffix = substr(FILENAME, RSTART, RLENGTH)
        gsub(/_/, ",", suffix)
    }

    # print each data line with suffix
    FNR>1 { print $0 "," suffix }

' ZZ_OUT????_??_??_??_??_??_csvfile.csv >output.csv
```

`nextfile` is widely supported but not completely portable - check your awk supports it.

So-called "interval expressions" (eg `[0-9]{4}`) are specified by POSIX but are not accepted by several versions of awk (eg. `mawk`).

Here's an alternative version that uses neither `nextfile` nor interval expressions:

```
awk '
    # filter out ill-formed filenames
    BEGIN {
         d4 = "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
        ud2 = "_[0-9][0-9]"
        regex = d4 ud2 ud2 ud2 ud2 ud2

        for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++)
            if ( !match(ARGV[i], regex) )
                ARGV[i] = ""
    }

    NR==1 { print $0 ",YYYY,MM,DD,HH,TT,SS" }

    FNR==1 {
        # this will always succeed
        match(FILENAME, regex)

        suffix = substr(FILENAME, RSTART, RLENGTH)
        gsub(/_/, ",", suffix)
    }

    FNR>1 { print $0 "," suffix }
' ZZ_OUT*.csv >output.csv
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has solved my issue completely. Bundle of thanks.

Comment: @EdMorton oops :-(  is there a simple alternative? getline loop till FNR==1 again maybe?

Comment: @EdMorton ah, gawk's `abandon()` or null out the ARGV elements in BEGIN

Comment: I'm thinking have the OP process the filenames into a temp file (e.g. `find .. | sort > tmp` or `ls -1 > tmp`, etc..) and then have awk process the temp file. Eliminates the whole `nextfile` issue.

Comment: IMHO what you did in the BEGIN section to remove file names from ARGV[] is the best approach. You should start the loop at 1 instead of 0 though as ARGV[0] is the name of the command, the first file name is in ARGV[1].

Comment: FWIW I had to think about and test `match(ARGV[i], regex) || ARGV[i] = ""` before convincing myself it'd actually work. I'm not sure if it's really portable, I don't think I've ever come across that construct used standalone in an awk action block and thought you'd mistaken awk for shell for a minute. Personally I'll stick to `if ( !match(ARGV[i], regex) ) ARGV[i] = ""` as IMO it's clearer and it's only a couple more characters.

Comment: @EdMorton `i=0` was a transcripton error. My test code had 1. I actually did originally have `if` but thought the `||` was easier to read without the brackets and negations. :-) I have no strong preference

Comment: @EdMorton I fairly certain my use of `||` follows the grammar: an assignment on either arm is allowed but will need parentheses for precedence if on the lhs. And it seems identical to its use in a pattern.

Comment: You might be right, I just don't recall ever seeing a condition used that way outside of a `condition { action }` or `if/while/etc ( condition )` context and you can't do `condition { action }` inside an action block so I was surprised to see a standalone `condition` in that context.